# Clp ECLiPSe Prolog Dynamic Constraint

Tags: dynamic, prolog, eclipse-clp

I have this constraint:

```
B #> P1*V1 + P2*V2 + P3*V3+ P4*V4 + P5*V5 + P6*V6 +P7*V7 + P8*V8 + P9*V9 + P10*V10
```

with `P=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] and V=[V1,V2,V3,....], V::0..1`

I want implement this constraint in dynamic way with `N` elements (cardinality of `P` and `V` will be `N`).

If I implement this with a cycle I have problem of instantiation because `V` is not yet labeled at this point of code.

---

#### Solved

I've resolved the question using scalar product `B #> P*V` implemented directly in CLP.

Answer (score 0):

that's an instance of '[scalar product](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=scalar_product/4)', in ECLiPSe you can find it in [Eplex Instances](http://eclipseclp.org/doc/libman/libman054.html). But I don't understand your problem, V will be labelled when you instruct the system to do, isn't this true ? Then you can post your expressions as usual.

Comment: Now I have this constraint (scalar product of P and V must be less then B) with cardinality 10 and it work, but I want realize this constraint in dynamic way with N elements. P is labeled, V is not labelled, and will be labelled after the declaration of this constraint.